# libhdfs throws Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool error when running through callgrind

Tags: java-native-interface, hdfs, valgrind, callgrind, libhdfs

I am trying to run one my process through callgrind. One of the child process (that I need to trace) calls into libhdfs and when running through callgrind this throws an exception:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2602)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem.<init>(ViewFileSystem.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file com/sun/proxy/$Proxy7
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:685)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:592)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:244)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:455)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.getProxyForCallback(MetricsSystemImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.MetricsSystem.register(MetricsSystem.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    ... 9 more
```

When running normally I do not get this exception. Any idea what's going on? I am new to valgrind/callgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is an issue with JVM which generates a lot of SIGSEGVs during it's normal course of operation which valgrind doesn't like. I overcame that with the following parameter to callgrind `--vex-iropt-register-updates=allregs-at-mem-access`.